# Camera support and scanners

Tags: html, camera, twain, image-scanner

So I followed the simple instructions for getting a webcam working in HTML5 here:
http://davidwalsh.name/browser-camera

It works perfectly. When the software loads, the browser asks which camera you would like to share.  You chose the one you want and the image comes up.

But I was wondering if there is a way to possibly trick the browser into thinking that my scanner is a webcam so I can use that as an image source instead.

I imagine I would have to create some kind of wrapper around the TWAIN driver but I don't have a clue how to begin.

Any ideas?